Was the saddle Rachel was sitting on, on the camel when her father was searching for the Terafim?
I remember reading somewhere (I don’t remember where) that when Lavan was searching for his Terafim, Rachel was sitting on her camel with the saddle beneath her.
However, all the Pasuk says is that she was sitting on the saddle of the camel - is there any reliable source that Rachel was actually sitting on the camel?

Uh, of course there was no camel in the tent?
